# nock: is there a way to get a list of unsatisfaedMocks?

Tags: node.js, mocking, tdd, nock

I want to have a code like this:

```
describe('populate', function() {
    it('should grab ', function() {
        nock('http://someapi.com')
            .post('/attractions')
            .reply(200, [])

        return request
          .post('http://someapi.com/wrong')
          .send({destId: id})
          .catch(() => 
            expect(nock.unsatisfaedMocks()).is.eql(['http://someapi.com/wrong'])
          )
    })
})
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can

we usually stick for 
`assert.strictEqual(nock.isDone(), true, nock.pendingMocks())`

`nock.isDone()` checks if all defined nock are triggered (globally)
`nock.pendingMocks()` returns array of not-called nocks